# Symfony5.4 importing services from private package

Tags: php, symfony

I have a company package where autoload PSR-4 looks like that in composer.json

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "Projects\\Engine\\": "Engine/"
  }
},
```

but when I try to load that in my Symfony project, I get an error indicating that it cannot find that package.

composer.json in Symfony project looks like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/",
        "Projects\\Engine\\": "vendor/projects/engine/"
    }
},
```

this doesn't work so I also changed services.yaml to look something like that

```
Projects\:
    resource: '../vendor/projects/engine/*'
    exclude:
        - '../vendor/projects/engine/tests/*'
    autowire: true
```

This is my first package so a lot is not right for sure.
I question how to make it so I can use DependencyIjnection with it. I can edit all files

Comment: Start with the basics.  Ignoring services for now does $obj = new Projects\Engine\SomeClass(); work?

Comment: It's working, I can extend or create instance